# Is any part of the Magna Carta considered valid US law?

Tags: united-states, common-law, magna-carta

Is any part of the Magna Carta currently considered valid US law?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Magna Carta acted as an origin of many legal concepts of today, includng the English, and thus US, common law system.  It clearly affected the Founders' views of government and was instrumental in creation of the US constitution.

But no provision of the Magna Carta would be considered on its own to be valid US law.